# Does let create two blocks in for loop?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
function A() {
  let local = "local";

  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var var_variable = "var_variable";
    const k = 10;
    {
      var block = "block";
    }
    function inside() {
      console.log("yo");
    }
    inside();
  }
}

A();
```

[image: chrome dev tools]

I know `let` and `const` are *block scoped*.

If you see from the image, let variable `i` has an own *block* and the `for` loop block which contain `const` scoped to that *block* and `var` which is scoped to that execution context.

My question is does let get copied into the for loop block in each iteration and destroyed?

Comment: I think the specs should answer your question : https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-for-statement-runtime-semantics-labelledevaluation

Answer (score -1):

`let` basically allows that variable be used within that scope, as you mention you're familiar with. To answer your question, it's valid within the `for` loop until the end of the scope of that block of code. It's not "copied in" every time, the variable `i` is made at the call of the for() loop, then cleared / lost when the for loop ends.

See https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_let.asp for more info on scopes